# Trigger function on jquery addon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hard time searching for a solution to this.

I've downloaded a pageslider jQuery addon, but i would like a function to trigger each time the pageslider triggers.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugin-For-Responsive-Page-Slide-Menu-PageSlide.html

```
function horse(){
    alert("hey");
}

$(".second").pageslide({ direction: "left", horse() });
```

Any ideas?

This setup doesn't work, but not sure what else to do.

Thanks!

Comment: you can check in the plugin to see if they have any custom events triggered. or give a reference to the plugin so that someone will look it for you if you don't understand that code. But first check their  docs

Comment: It doesn't help that you don't provide **which** pageslider plugin you're using

Comment: This is all the docs i have. I'm trying to figure out their js file
http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugin-For-Responsive-Page-Slide-Menu-PageSlide.html

Comment: https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-pageslide/blob/master/jquery.pageslide.js is the source, they dont have any such hooks

Comment: Their GitHub page says `Note: This respository is not actively maintained. In fact, I don't recommend using it. There are plenty of alternatives out there.` (with a link to the alternatives)

Comment: You have a couple of options; find a similar plugin that has some callbacks for this; bind click/swipe on the element yourself; modify the code and trigger some events yourself. With your knowledge of javascript I would suggest you to search and find a plugin that has callbacks or custom events for page sliding.